# React 'react-data-table-component' doesn't show a tool tip when hover if the text is long

Tags: reactjs

I use 'react-data-table-component' to display my data to table view.
If the text is longer than the size of the cell, it appears as "..." at the end but the thing is when I hover there is no tooltip showing full text.

My question is does the library support tooltip or it does but my code is missing that part?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';    

export default class MyTable2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      data.push({ id: i, title: 'Lorem Ipsum' + i, summary: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, morbi molestie sagittis. Fusce neque pharetra elementum ante praesent et, non non nulla enim, velit amet sit convallis sit, sit donec ac odio quis sem.', year: '1982', expanderDisabled: true, image: 'http://conan.image.png' })
    }

    this.state = {
      rs: data
    }
  }

  render() {    

    const columns = [
      {
        name: 'Title',
        selector: 'title',
        sortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'Summary',
        selector: 'summary',
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Year',
        selector: 'year',
        sortable: true
      },
    ];

    const myNewTheme = {
      rows: {
        fontSize: '25px'
      }
    }

    const handleChange = (state) => {
      console.log('Selected Rows: ', state.selectedRows);
    };

    return (
      <DataTable         
        className="dataTables_wrapper"
        noHeader
        columns={columns}
        data={this.state.rs}
        selectableRows // add for checkbox selection
        onTableUpdate={handleChange}
        pagination
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: I add the reference of the library that I use [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component)

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It could just be a css-styles problem, something like `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in some css classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **width** property:

```
{
        name: 'Proveedor',
        selector: 'PROVEEDOR',
        sortable: true,
        center: true,
        style: {
            justifyContent: 'left',
        },
        width: '300px'
    },
```